# Can one file German tax returns twice for the same year?

Tags: germany, taxes

Recently I found out you can file for tax returns on paid university tuition. I studied in a private German University.

2018 was my first working year in Germany. When I filed for the tax returns (SteuerGo) for that year, I didn't include the tuition I paid to the university.

Can I include those payments in this year's filing?

Comment: Is there a process to file an amendment to a previous tax return?

Comment: @Traveller I have no idea honestly

Answer (score 1):

Check this site: 
https://www.steuerklassen.com/steuererklaerung/ratgeber/steuererklaerung-korrigieren/

Basically, within one month after you receive the reply to your income tax declaration you can easily fix mistakes.

After that it’s difficult. You can ask the Finanzamt to please fix your mistake, and if they do, you are fine. If they don’t you’d have to go to court (and I think your chances are slim since it’s your own fault).

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a short summary of thev3 conditions the link states. The time before the **tax assessment** is issued (easy, per simple letter) ; time after **tax assessment** has been issued (3+30 days) and  becomes binding ; time after it becomes binding.

Comment: I asked the Finanzamt and they said it's not possible to re-do 2018. They said I could put the amount in the 2019 tax return form, but they don't know if it works or not.